# Is it possible to disable the overlayfs directory cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, overlayfs

I have a process that's continuously writing files into a directory structure that looks like:

`152527
├── 1525270000000
│   ├── 01be6dc0b6e3e087.json
│   ├── 067e2490bb7ee05c.json
│   ├── 15ec3513bf7deef6.json
├── 1525270010000
│   ├── 01be6dc0b6e3e087.json
│   ├── 067e2490bb7ee05c.json
│   ├── 15ec3513bf7deef6.json
...`

The directories are written to a series of mounts, `/mnt/fs_01`, `/mnt_fs_02`, `/mnt/fs_03`, all combined into a read-only `overlayfs` of `/mnt/fs_all`.

A set of processes writes to a single mount at a time; the same set of processes reads from the combined `/mnt/fs_all`. (It's a uWSGI application.)

The problem is that fairly often, a new directory will be created in an underlying file system, but it doesn't show up on read.

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) on `overlayfs` mentions:

> When a 'readdir' request is made on a merged directory, the upper and
>   lower directories are each read and the name lists merged in the
>   obvious way (upper is read first, then lower - entries that already
>   exist are not re-added).  This merged name list is cached in the
>   'struct file' and so remains as long as the file is kept open.  If the
>   directory is opened and read by two processes at the same time, they
>   will each have separate caches.  A seekdir to the start of the
>   directory (offset 0) followed by a readdir will cause the cache to be
>   discarded and rebuilt.
>
> This means that changes to the merged directory do not appear while a
>   directory is being read.  This is unlikely to be noticed by many
>   programs.

Unfortunately, this is noticed by my program.

I can implement the `seekdir` suggestion, but I'd prefer to disable the cache altogether if possible.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not without making the performance absolutely horrible, and then overlayfs would be close to useless.

Comment: I know performance would be worse without the cache, but if I'm issuing a separate clear command every single time I read, I'd imagine it's not that different.